# Problem with showing results in a Manipulate in a cdf-file

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format

I have a problem with showing my results correctly in a Manipulate in a cdf-file.

My program (for my bachelor thesis) can calculate the income law with a income entered into an input field; the use can also define some other parameters.

When I start this program (klicking on "Berechnen") in a notebook file, all results are shown correctly in the output. However, when I start the program as a demonstration, I only see the code of the "Einkommensteuer" and not the number.

Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Text@TraditionalForm@
   Pane[Text[Column[{"Einkommensteuer:", "", Style[Row[{Which[
           j == "2013" \[And] p == "alleinstehend", 
           Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]],
           j == "2013" \[And]  p == "verheiratet", 
           Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]],
           j == "2014" \[And]  p == "alleinstehend", 
           Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]],
           j == "2014" \[And] p == "verheiratet", 
           Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]]], "\[Euro]"}], 
        FontColor -> farbe], "", "Solidaritätszuschlag:", "", 
       Style[Row[{Dynamic[Which[
            j == "2013" \[And] p == "alleinstehend", 
            Soli[Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]], p],
            j == "2013" \[And]  p == "verheiratet", 
            Soli[Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]], p],
            j == "2014" \[And]  p == "alleinstehend", 
            Soli[Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]], p],
            j == "2014" \[And] p == "verheiratet", 
            Soli[Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]], p]]], " \[Euro]"}], 
        FontColor -> farbe], "", "Kirchensteuer:", "", 
       Style[Row[{Dynamic[Which[
            j == "2013" \[And] p == "alleinstehend", 
            Kst[Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]], k],
            j == "2013" \[And]  p == "verheiratet", 
            Kst[Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]], k],
            j == "2014" \[And]  p == "alleinstehend", 
            Kst[Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]], k],
            j == "2014" \[And] p == "verheiratet", 
            Kst[Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]], k]]], " \[Euro]"}], 
        FontColor -> farbe], "", "Nettoeinkommen:", "", 
       Style[Row[{Which[
           j == "2013" \[And] p == "alleinstehend", 
           a - Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]] - 
            Soli[Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]], p] - 
            Kst[Floor[Ekst13[a, hilfsy13[a]]], k],
           j == "2013" \[And]  p == "verheiratet", 
           a - Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]] - 
            Soli[Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]], p] - 
            Kst[Floor[2*Ekst13[a/2, hilfsy13[a/2]]], k],
           j == "2014" \[And]  p == "alleinstehend", 
           a - Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]] - 
            Soli[Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]], p] - 
            Kst[Floor[Ekst[a, hilfsy[a]]], k],
           j == "2014" \[And] p == "verheiratet", 
           a - Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]] - 
            Soli[Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]], p] - 
            Kst[Floor[2*Ekst[a/2, hilfsy[a/2]]], k]], " \[Euro]"}], 
        FontColor -> farbe]}]], ImageSize -> {200, 300}, 
    ImageMargins -> 10], "Berechnung der Einkommensteuer",
 "", {{a, 0, "Zu versteuerndes Einkommen"}, ControlType -> InputField,
   ImageSize -> {100, 20}}, {{e, "2013", "Jahr"}, {"2013", "2014"}, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {{p, "alleinstehend", 
   "Persönliche Verhältnisse"}, {"alleinstehend", "verheiratet"}, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {{farbe, White, ""}, 
  ControlType -> None}, {{k, "0 %", "Kirchensteuer"}, {"0 %", "8 %", 
   "9 %"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, Delimiter, 
 Row[{Spacer[30], 
   Row[{Button["Berechnen", {farbe = Black}, ImageSize -> {100, 30}]}],
   Spacer[10],
   Button[
    "Zurücksetzen", {a = 0, e = "2013", p = "alleinstehend", 
     k = "0 %", farbe = White}, ImageSize -> {100, 30}]}
  ], ControlPlacement -> Left, ContinuousAction -> True, 
 Initialization :> (Ekst[a_, b_] := 
    Floor[Which[a <= 8354, 0, 
      a > 8354 \[And] a <= 13469, (974.58*b + 1400)*b, 
      a >= 13470 \[And] a <= 52881, (228.74*b + 2397)*b + 971, 
      a >= 52882 \[And] a <= 250730, 0.42*a - 8239, a >= 250731, 
      0.45*a - 15761]];
   hilfsy[a_] := 
    Which[Floor[a] >= 8355 \[And] 
      Floor[a] <= 13469, (Floor[a] - 8354)/10000, 
     Floor[a] >= 13470 \[And] Floor[a] <= 52881, (Floor[a] - 13469)/
      10000];
   Ekst13[a_, b_] := 
    Floor[Which[a <= 8130, 0, 
      a > 8131 \[And] a <= 13469, (933.70*b + 1400)*b, 
      a > 13470 \[And] a <= 52881, (228.74*b + 2397)*b + 1014, 
      a > 52882 \[And] a <= 250730, 0.42*a - 8196, a > 250731, 
      0.45*a - 15718]];
   hilfsy13[a_] := 
    Which[Floor[a] >= 8131 \[And] 
      Floor[a] <= 13469, (Floor[a] - 8130)/10000, 
     Floor[a] >= 13470 \[And] Floor[a] <= 52881, (Floor[a] - 13469)/
      10000];
   Soli[a_, p_] := 
    If[a < 972, 0, 
     Which[p == "alleinstehend", Min[0.2*(a - 972), 0.055*a], 
      p == "verheiratet", Min[0.2*(a - 1944), 0.055*a]]];
   Kst[a_, b_] := 
    Which[b == "0 %", 0, b == "8 %", 0.08*a, b == "9 %", 0.09*a];)]
```

How can I fix this problem?

P.S.: Sorry for my english ;-), not my mother tongue.

Comment: Even in a notebook file, all I see under `Einkommensteuer:` is code.

Comment: hm, strange...
I show you a pic how it looks like in my mathematica-software:
http://img4.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/ekst31zqncb2sl.png
On the left in a cdf-file, on the right how it should look in a cdf-file and not only in a nb-file

Comment: a = 0 and p = alleinstehend at the beginning...
Both are defined in the parametres...

Comment: I replaced `e` by `j` where it appears in your code, and it runs fine.  And, the cdf runs fine too, at least in preview mode.

Comment: Sure, I see the wrong e...
Now it works :-)
little fault, big consequence

Comment: Happy to help.  For completeness, I documented the solution as an Answer.  Good luck with your thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing two instances of `e` by `j` in the code allows it to run correctly both as a notebook and a cdf.

Comment: four eyes are better than only two

Comment: @Manu Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)